# Python MemoryError without memory consumption

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I'm repeatedly getting a `MemoryError` exception in a Python script which should not store so much that it should run out of memory.  Also, viewing it on my Linux system using things like `top` also shows that it does not consume memory in a significant amount: `top` shows it at 0.9% memory usage (growing steadily from 0.0%), while other processes linger at ~10% memory usage, so this does not seem to be the reason.  The problem also is reproducibly and always happens at the same spot, so it does not seem to be dependent on the overall system memory load.

Concretely, the exception is thrown by a `read()` command which should read ~64k of data from a recently opened file into memory.

I'm using *one* data structure which grows, that's a `defaultdict` to store `int`s pointing to `list`s of `str`s.  We are talking about 44028 `int`s, 260830 `list`s altogether and 21073549 characters in all `str`s together.  I guess that should not blast my system.

I've searched on SO for such a phenomenon but have found no other questions which looked like my situation.

Are there known effects which can make a process have a `MemoryError` without really using much memory?  Maybe a certain kind of stack overflow?  Too many generators in use?  Too many entries in a `dict`?  Too many open files?  (These are all ideas I checked before asking or which just do not apply to my situation, but maybe you get the point.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the output of `limit`?

Comment: What is `limit`?  Within Python?  What do I have to import?  Or on the shell?  I've got no such command there.

Comment: you can try those commands: `cat /proc/proc-number/limits`  and `cat /proc/meminfo` to see limits for your process and meminfo for the system.

Comment: You didn't specify the OS or environment where you are running it so I just assumed a Linux/BSD system, which should include a `limit` command. But since you don't have it, I'm guessing you're using Windows instead?

Comment: I've written in the question that I'm Linux based.  I'm using an Ubuntu 12.04, and there is no `limit` installed (and no package for installing it is suggested when I type it).  I will check more when I'm back on the computer.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain what I could have made better?  Or revoke the downvote?  Now that I've found the reason myself I think this question contains some valuable information and shouldn't be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason by trying to strip down the script to a minimal example (which took some time and thus wasn't my first choice ;-)

I was using a large value to `read()`, larger by far than the files' sizes.  To be precise I had this piece of code:

```
with open(filePath) as f:
    s = f.read(chunk)
```

Where `chunk` was `1 << 30` (1GiB).  This normally returns the whole file contents, but it probably internally allocates a very large buffer of the given size first and frees it as soon as the reading took place.  And after running for some time, some additional memory was used, and this failed as described.

I tried it with an even larger value of `1 << 40` (1TiB) and then got the `MemoryError` at once and all the time.

I now replaced the code by using `s = f.read(min(chunk, fileSize))` so in case the `chunk` is extremely large, only `fileSize` is used.

Thank you all for your consideration nevertheless!